# swapping the order of a multibyte

Tags: java

I have the following multi-byte represented in hex format:

```
0xdc, 0xd3
```

I can process the bytes in little endian () format to get the decimal value 54236:

```
List<Integer> packet = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0xdc, 0xd3 ));
int idx=0;
int rpm = (int)readBytes(packet, idx, 2);

private long readBytes(List<Integer> packet, int idx, int size){
    long val=0;
    int element;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++, idx++){
        element = packet.get(idx);
        val |= element << (8 * i);
    }

    return val;
}
```

The above method produces the value as expected. However, now I want to get the value in the reverse order (big endian format), but it gives me some crazy value of 14471936:

```
private long bigEndianReadBytes(List<Integer> packet, int idx, int size){
    long val=0;
    int element;

    for(int i=size;i>0;i--, idx++){
        element = packet.get(idx);
        val |= element << (8 * i);
    }

    return val;
}
```

What might be wrong with this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop in your `bigEndianReadBytes()` method should start by shifting `size - 1` bytes, and end by shifting zero bytes (in the last iteration).  Currently, you are shifting `size` bytes in the first iteration, and one byte in the last iteration.  Try this code instead:

```
for (int i=size-1; i >= 0; i--, idx++) {
    element = packet.get(idx);
    val |= element << (8 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With @TimBiegeleisen answer (+1), you have good "manual" code to for converting bytes to values.

Have you considered using a `ByteBuffer`?  It does all this for you and works with both Big Endian and Little Endian.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    bb.put(new byte[] {(byte)0xdc, (byte)0xd3});
    System.out.println(bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getShort(0) & 0xFFFF);
    System.out.println(bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort(0) & 0xFFFF);      
}
```

`AND`ing the result against `0xFFFF` so the `short` result is promoted to an `int`, otherwise the result is a negative number because java works with signed data types.

Results:

```
56531
54236
```